# Prevent Url.HttpRouteUrl from lower-casing ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a URL using `Url.HttpRouteUrl` -- however, when I passed an id, it lower-cases it. Is there a way to force it to not change the case?

Example:

```
var id = "Abc";
this.Url.HttpRouteUrl("Route", new {id}); ==> "<host>/<route>/abc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` set, probably in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs, or do you have a lowercase URLs rule set through IIS/Rewrite?